# FailoverBehaviour - what is considered as server being down

Tags: c#, ravendb

I do have 2 `RavenDB` boxes replicating each other as a `Fail-Over`.

My setting on `IDocumentStore` is:

```
 Conventions =
                {
                    FailoverBehavior =
                           FailoverBehavior.AllowReadsFromSecondariesAndWritesToSecondaries
                }
```

According to the documentation - RavenDB will failover to next server when first (master) is down.

Problem is - how I should understand

> Server is down

?

Does the box must be off, RavenDB service off, or is there any other mechanism in place that checks heart-beat, time of responses etc?

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following things will cause the client to consider being down:

- Name resolution error (name not found, dns not resolved, etc)
- TCP connection error (can't reach server, connection refused, etc)
- Timeout (TCP connection timeout)
- HTTP reply with status code `502`, `503`, `504`, `408`.

The following will NOT cause the client to failover:

- Any HTTP error that isn't `502`, `503`, `504`, `408`.
- In particular, `500` server error or `404` will be shown to the user.

The `404` case is important, because if you take down a website in IIS, that is what it will return, instead of the expected `503`.

Comment: What is default timeout for the connection? And can that be modified?

Comment: IIRC, 15 seconds, and yes, you can modify that.